# Did the U.S. propose solutions to the functioning of the Appellate Body at the WTO?

Tags: united-states, wto

> But the key here, regardless of whether it is the Appellate Body
> specifically or dispute settlement more generally, is to make actual
> proposals for reform. **It is fine for the United States to have
> objections to the functioning of the Appellate Body or the broader
> system. But if it has specific concerns, it needs to propose
> solutions.** This applies whether we are talking about the narrow
> “Appellate Body crisis” or the broader “WTO dispute settlement
> reform.”

https://www.iisd.org/articles/united-states-must-propose-solutions-end-wto-dispute-settlement-crisis

Did the U.S. propose solutions to the functioning of the Appellate Body at the WTO? The U.S. blocked the WTO process, because it has issues with the functioning of the Appellate Body, and from the article it seems it never proposed any solution, but the article was written a year ago, since then did the U.S. propose any solution on how to solve the WTO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No US official sources publicly seem to have said this, but Politico [reported](https://www.politico.eu/article/reform-die-usa-washington-world-trade-organization-wto-ngozi-okonjo-iweala-joe-biden/) in May:

> The new U.S. idea is to only allow a trade dispute to advance beyond the first non-binding judgment to the legally-binding Appellate Body stage if both the plaintiff and the defendant agree to move ahead, according to people with knowledge of the talks who were granted anonymity because the discussions are preliminary and confidential.
>
> Washington also wants to roll back some of the Appellate Body's previous interpretations of international trade law. For instance, the U.S. wants to let countries decide for themselves when they can invoke a national security exception — a joker that can be played to legally violate trade rules — rather than let the Appellate Body decide.

(There's a summary [here](https://asiatimes.com/2023/06/testing-the-limits-of-wto-security-exceptions/) of those cases involving national security invocations.)

Officially:

> “The United States is actively engaging and contributing in the brainstorming exercise facilitated by the WTO,” a spokesperson for U.S. Trade Representative Katherine Tai said in a statement to POLITICO. “Those issues stem from the work done in the interest-based discussions led by the United States over the last two years.”